# onUnselect event of jquery easyui datagrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using JQuery EasyUI 1.3.4, I am having some trouble catching onUnselect event, following code illustrates my problem:

```
function NavigateProcess() {

$(function () {

    var data = list;
    $('#dg').datagrid({
        view: detailview,
        cache: true,
        data: data,
        loadMsg: 'Processing, please wait …',
        singleSelect: true,
        columns: [[
                        {
                            title: 'Name', field: 'Name', width: 180, editor: 'text'
                            //,formatter: formatProgress
                        },
                        { field: 'ID', title: 'ID', width: 60, align: 'right', editor: 'text' },
                        { field: 'RatePlan', title: 'RatePlan', width: 80, editor: 'text' },
                        { field: 'ActivationDate', title: 'ActivationDate', width: 80, editor: 'text' },
                        { field: 'DataType', title: 'DataType', hidden: 'true' }
        ]],
        onUnselect: function (rowIndex, rowData) {
            alert('unselect');
            if (lastselectedrow) {
                $('#dg').datagrid('endEdit', lastselectedrow);
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (rowIndex, rowData) {
            alert('select');
            lastselectedrow = rowIndex;
            $('#dg').datagrid('beginEdit', rowIndex);

        },
        detailFormatter: function (index, row) {
            return '<div style="padding:1px"><table id="ddv-' + index + '"></table></div>';
        }
    });
});
function doSearch() {
    $('#tt').datagrid('load', {
        itemid: $('#itemid').val(),
        productid: $('#productid').val()
    });

}
```

}

I put two alert statements in onSelect and onUnselect events, onSelect is triggered when I click on a row. Since singleSelect property is true, selecting another row will result in an onUnselect and onSelect events, at least that's my understanding. When I click on rows only onSelect alert pops up, alert of onUnselect never pops up, can somebody point me how to capture onUnselect event? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please put this example in http://www.jsfiddle.net, including your HTML, that might help us debug a bit easier.

Comment: I couldn't make the example work on jsfiddle, I am trying to understand when onUnselect event fires, if I figure that out, I will solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to see if any javascript errors happen when you unselect? (Using the Firebug or Chrome Developer Toolbars)?

Comment: I just tried with firebug, no errors found, only select event is fired.

Comment: is there a way to manually invoke unselect event?

Comment: Ok I figured it out, there is a unselectRow method that can called manually.

Answer (score 0):

there is an inherent bug that prevents invoking onUnselect event